# How to use npm link command in Azure pipelines

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, spfx

I have created SPFX library module in which there is code to be shared with multiple webparts similar to the one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/library-component-tutorial). I used `npm link <lib name>` command to link it. It works pretty well in the local environment as well as when I deploy it manually in SharePoint online app catalog. But if I deploy it using Azure Pipelines (YAML script) it always throws and error for library not found.

I have made it sure that the library is built first and then other webparts are built in pipeline (by introducting stages) but still it doesn't find the library. Is there a way to run npm link as a pipeline task?

Comment: Is the library first built in an stage/job and the other webparts are built in a different stage/job in pipeline? This can cause the library and the webparts reside in different agents. Could you share a sample of your pipeline yaml file?

Comment: yes that is correct, it is in a different stage, just to make sure it is built first, but I will try adding to the same jobs sequence

Comment: I tried that as well but it failed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the solutions posted above it still didn't work so I published it as NPM package using `npm publish` command. This solved the problem.
We can also use this command in YAML to automatically publish the package everytime we build but that was not required in my case so I didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is first built in a different stage or job, the library will not be located in the same agent machine with the other webparts.

Let's say the library is built in Stage A and the other webparts are built in Stage B. As workaround, you will need to publish the library as artifacts to azure devops server using [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) in stage A. And then download the library to the agent which builds the other webparts in Stage B using [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

For below example:

The library is built in stage A and published to azure devops server as artifacts named `library`.

In Stage B, the library artifacts  is downloaded from azure devops server to folder `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. Then you can refer to the library by path `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/library` for the following tasks in Stage B.

If multiple webparts are built in different jobs in Stage B, each job in Stage B will need to download the library artifacts, for different jobs run on different agent virtual machines.

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Library
    pool: 
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
    steps:
    ...
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: {path to the library}
        ArtifactName: library


- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: WebParts1
    pool: 
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
    steps:

    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        buildType: current
        artifactName: library
    ...

  - job: WebParts2
    pool: 
      vmImage: "windows-latest"
    steps:

    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        downloadPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
        buildType: current
        artifactName: library
    ...
```

Comment: but I have tried in the same stage as well,, it doesn't pick anything. But I will try this approach as well.

Comment: this also did not work :(,, even tried using npm link in scope of $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/library and $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/webpart folders. But I'm going to try another approach now. If that works, i'll post it here

Comment: Hi @MujtabaHassan Did you find a fix to this issu? Could you share a sample of your pipeline yaml file?

Comment: Hi, Yes unfortunately it didn't work with pipeline so I had to publish it as npm package. After that it started picking it up automatically